# Enter and Save username and password into same file

Tags: python, passwords

I want a user to be able to enter a new username and password and it saves it into the **same file** so it can be used for the login process that would come after. The user should be able to enter a new username into an `input` and the same for the password then it is saved to the file to be used later. I would do this myself but i don't know how to save it to the same file.

```
import time
import sys

uun = "test"
uun01 = "test01"
uun02 = "test02"
usernames = (uun+uun01+uun02)

upw = "test"
upw01 = "test01"
upw02 = "test02"
passwords = (upw+upw01+upw02)

max_attempts = 3
attempts = 0

while True:
    print("Username")
    username = input("")

    print("Password")
    password = input("")

    if username in usernames and password in passwords:
        print("Access Granted")
    else:
        attempts+=1
        if attempts >= max_attempts:
            print(f"reached max attempts of {attempts} ")
            sys.exit()
        print("Try Again (10 sec)")
        time.sleep(10)
        continue
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I do when deciding how to file data is think about how I want to access it later - this determines the data structure. A couple examples are, just straight key : value dictionary (username : password) to search by username or maybe entrytime : (username, password) to search by when the entry was made.

Once that is decided, format into a string and write to file. A simple print() of your data structure will show how it looks 'in the raw' and how you might want to format it for easy access later.